Cómo obtener la ruta de archivo en plugin wordpress?
estoy creando un plugin que lanza una tabla con registros, cada uno con su botón de editar y borrar.
Quiero que cuando se presione borrar en cualquier registro, se llame a un jquery y ejecute el archivo borrar.php?codigo=
Me falta construir la URI para enviarle la pagina via ajax.
$('.btnBorrarTC').click(
        function (){
            var info = $(this).attr("data-info");
            
            
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:link,
                success:function(r){
                    if(r == 1){
                        alert("Correcto");
                    } else {
                        alert("No se ha podido votar");
                   }
                }
            });
            return false;
      
            
        });

como es un plugin la direccion estática es
wp-admin/plugin/plugintext/admin/borrar.php
y quisiera hallar una forma dinamica de configurarlo con href o algo así. Es posible?
Saludos.

En wordpress, ajax funciona de forma diferente, se recomienda usar el sistema de hooks de wordpress por temas de seguridad, para ello, primero debes crear una función, conectarla al sistema de hooks de wp_ajax y por ultimo llamar a admin-ajax.php que es el archivo destinado para las llamadas ajax, por ejemplo:
Creamos una función que ejecutaremos por ajax.
function deleteTC(){

    $info = $_POST['info'];


    // Tu código

    echo 1;
    wp_die();
}

Ahora conectamos esa función a nuestros hooks de ajax:
// Ejecutamos la funcion
add_action( 'wp_ajax_deleteTC', 'deleteTC' ); // Agregamos el ajax para usuarios registrados
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_deleteTC', 'deleteTC' ); // Agregamos el ajax para usuarios no registrados

estos hooks reciben el nombre de la acción a ejecutar y la función php
Por ultimo, nuestro callback debe verse asi
$('.btnBorrarTC').click( function (){    

    var info = $(this).attr("data-info");
    $.ajax({
        url : 'https://misitio.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action  : 'deleteTC',
            info    : info
        },
        success:function(r){
            if(r == 1){
                alert("Correcto");
            } else {
                alert("No se ha podido votar");
           }
        }
    });

});

Todo debe pasar por admin.ajax.php y en data enviar el action a ejecutar, en este caso deleteTC y otras variables según necesites.

Gracias por contestar, pero no funciona.
He logrado construir el link hacia el archivo, por ejemplo https://misitio.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Pero al momento de ejecutar me sale error 400 bad request.
Intenté hacerlo también apuntando al archivo que contiene el codigo, pero tampoco me resulto (y eso que revisando la url si existe en la ubicación indicada)

Entonces haz debug, mi codigo funciona, eso seguro, asi que si algo falla debe ser en tu función.

Para enganchar un ajax desde un plugin tenes que pasarle la referencia a la clase donde esta definida la función que procesa la solicitud.
x ejemplo:
add_action(
  'wp_ajax_nopriv_miplugin_pagination',
  [&$this, 'load_more']
);
add_action(
  'wp_ajax_miplugin_pagination',
  [&$this, 'load_more']
);


En contexto quedaría algo así:
<?php

defined('MIPLUGIN_VERSION') || define('MIPLUGIN_VERSION', '24.6.1114');

class MiPluginClass
{
    public $version;
    public $url;
    public $path;

    public function __construct($version)
    {
        $this->version = $version;
        $this->url = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);
        $this->path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);

        /**
         * 
         * desde javascript el action será "miplugin_pagination"
         * la función/method que lo procesa es "MiPluginClass::load_more"
         * ó $this->load_more() 
         * esto se lo pasamos por referencia al hook de 
         * "usuarios logueados" anteponiendo 'wp_ajax_'
         * "usuarios no logueados" anteponiendo 'wp_ajax_nopriv_'
         * 
         */

        add_action(
            'wp_ajax_nopriv_miplugin_pagination',
            [&$this, 'load_more']
        );
        add_action(
            'wp_ajax_miplugin_pagination',
            [&$this, 'load_more']
        );

        /**
         * los scripts/assets van a necesitar ser cargados y configurados
         * lo hacemos tambien en un action pasandole la ref
         */

        add_action(
            'wp_enqueue_scripts',
            [&$this, 'enqueue_script'],
            10
        );

    }

    public function load_more()
    {

        /**
         * este nonce se genera al configurar y cargar el script
         */
        check_ajax_referer('miplugin_frontend_nonce', 'security');

        $data = [];
        $error = [];

        $paged = sanitize_text_field($_POST['paged']);

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 15,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'post_status' => ['publish'],
            'post_type' => 'post'
        );
        $query_posts = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($query_posts->have_posts()) {
            $data = [
                'total' => $query_posts->found_posts,
                'posts' => $query_posts->get_posts()
            ];
            // o un while/foreach para entregar el html ya cocido
        } else {
            $error[] = 'nomore';
        }
        wp_send_json(
            [
                'data' => $data,
                'error' => $error
            ]
        );

    }

    public function enqueue_script()
    {
        wp_register_script(
            'miplugin-script',
            $this->url . 'assets/js/frontend.js',
            ['jquery'],
            $this->version,
            true
        );
        wp_register_style(
            'miplugin-style',
            $this->url . 'assets/css/frontend.css',
            false,
            $this->version
        );

        /**
         * le pasamos al script un nonce y la url del procesador de ajax
         * x lo general 'ajax_url' como global está definido sólo en el backend
         * en javascript estas variables las vas a ver como
         * 
         * miplugin.ajax_url
         * miplugin.security
         * 
         */

        wp_localize_script(
            'miplugin-script',
            'miplugin',
            [
                'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
                'security' => wp_create_nonce('miplugin_frontend_nonce')
            ]
        );

        /**
         * normalmente uno registra los scripts y luego los enqueuea sólo donde se usan
         * x ej al renderizar un shortcode, widget, block 
         * o en un filter/hook o en un admin page etc..
         * aquí los enqueuamos justo despues de registrar y configurar
         */

        wp_enqueue_style('miplugin-style');
        wp_enqueue_script('miplugin-script');

    }

}

$mi_plugin = new MiPluginClass(MIPLUGIN_VERSION);



